# python/Flask: Route with dynamic first component

Tags: python, routes, flask

I am writing a Flask site for which I would like to have routes like this:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<page_id>')
@app.route('/<page_id>/<subpage_id>')
def page(page_id=None, subpage_id=None):
    ...
```

While it seems like this should work in theory, it looks like this actually breaks static resources located in the root static/ directory. I assume the reason for this is that my dynamic route actually matches 'static/style.css' and thus overrides the normal handler for static files.

Is there any way around this? Is there a 'static' handler I can forward the request to if I detect that page_id=='static'?

Edit: Here is a working sample

```
@app.route('/<page_id>/<subpage_id>/<subsubpage_id>')
def xxx(page_id=None, subpage_id=None, subsubpage_id=None):
    return 'hello'
```

If you open `http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/css/style.css` now you should get a 'hello' instead of the file.

Comment: If those variables are guaranteed to be ints, you can specify that in the route and that should help you. Otherwise, I'm not sure why this would be happening.

Comment: They are not ints unfortunately. I have just added a sample, if you insert that into the usual Flask skeleton the URL to the CSS should no longer work.

Comment: are you literally capturing `/<page>/<subpage>/<subsubpage>`?  what's the point of using routing if you have one function do everything?

Comment: Yes. I have Page objects in my database, which I load and display based on the page_id/subpage_id/subsubpage_id when the method is called. Is there a better way to do this?
I was thinking of adding separate routes for each of the pages when the app is initialized, but I could not find a good way of making that work in conjunction with url_for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the root of your problem:

> Yes. I have Page objects in my database, which I load and display based on the page_id/subpage_id/subsubpage_id when the method is called. Is there a better way to do this? I was thinking of adding separate routes for each of the pages when the app is initialized, but I could not find a good way of making that work in conjunction with url_for.

You can register route handlers directly by using [`app.add_url_rule`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule).  It will use the function's name for `url_for` by default, yes, but you can override that by passing an `endpoint` argument.

So maybe you'd have something like this:

```
from functools import partial

def actual_handler(page):
    return u'hello'

for page in session.query(Page):
    route = u'/{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(page.id1, page.id2, page.id3)
    app.add_url_rule(
        route,
        page.name,  # this is the name used for url_for
        partial(actual_handler, page=page),
    )
```

Getting the session may or may not be tricky, and may or may not involve work like manually calling `session.remove()`; I haven't tried using SQLAlchemy outside a Flask handler before.  Assuming you're using SQLA in the first place.

Also see the [documentation on route handling](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#url-route-registrations).

As for the original question of routes taking priority over static files, I genuinely don't know; based on my reading of the Flask and Werkzeug docs, that shouldn't happen.  If you still wish to solve this by manually serving static files, perhaps [`send_from_directory`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_from_directory) will help.  Presumably your web server will serve static files directly in production, anyway, so it might not be worth the metaprogramming gunk above.

PS: An afterthought; [Pyramid's traversal](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/traversal.html) might be a better fit if your entire site lives in a database.  It examines path components one at a time dynamically, rather than having a fixed list of static routes.

Comment: I think I got this to work, thank you! I don't understand why I need to get the session at all though. Why can't I just do `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` and then `for page in Page.query.all(): ...`?

Comment: you don't, really; `Page.query` is a shortcut for `session.query(Page)`.  i just like to use the vanilla SQLA approach as much as possible; it doesn't make sense to me that a table could query itself  :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a horrible hack but you could probably just do something akin to:

```
@app.route('/<page_id>/<subpage_id>/<subsubpage_id>')
def xxx(page_id=None, subpage_id=None, subsubpage_id=None):
    if page_id == 'static':  # or whatever the path is to your assets
       # make a response where you've filled the request yourself
    return 'hello'
```

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my original post I could do this if I knew what the default handler for static resource requests was, so that I could forward the request correcly. Do you know?