# Dynamically generate routes for Flask using blueprints

Tags: google-app-engine, flask

I like to generate routes for my Flask app hosted on Google App Engine. Currently I am using blueprints to generate routes. For instance

```
conference_routes = Blueprint('conference_routes', __name__)


@conference_routes.route('/home/Conferences/QCCC-Mappleton-2015')
def mappleton_conference():
    return render_template('Mappleton-2015.html')
```

And then I register the blueprint like so from the main.py

```
app.register_blueprint(conference_routes)
```

This is becoming really cumbersome, especially when we have over 100 routes. I wish to define routes in a database and dynamically construct them at runtime.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349852/2676531) answer shows the use of [`.add_url_rule`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule):

```
for page in session.query(Page):
route = u'/{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(page.id1, page.id2, page.id3)
app.add_url_rule(
    route,
    page.name,  # this is the name used for url_for
    partial(actual_handler, page=page),
)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19238118/2676531) answer has useful information for setting up those routes, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17880335/2676531) also has several good examples.

It sounds like you'll want to add all of your routing right after setting up your app variable:

```
conference_routes = Flask(__name__)
# load info from database
# insert routes
```

If your files are all 1-1 like your example, then you don't even need that route loading method - just look for the file from the url:

```
@conference_routes.route('/<path:path>')
def search_file(path):
    # (in)validate path
    # return html template or 404
```